# Is id in Objective C is primitive data type

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I am bit confused, as my title mentioned,

Is `id` in Objective C is primitive data type? or Object type? I always thought that `id` is Object type as it is pointing towards an object.

So, Is it Object type or Primitive data type?

Comment: why do you think it is a primitive type?

Comment: Not sure but I'd say its an object type. The base for all object types. Maybe the most primitive object? Awesome question haha.

Comment: @Pfitz, Well I thought it's Object type

Comment: @RyanPoolos, Mate...As per the Paul Hegarty Stanford lecturer and former software engineer who was part of the team who build cocoa-touch platform says that id is primitive type :)...Finally the confusion is gone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` is declared in [objc.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.2/runtime/objc.h) as

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

so yes, I'd say it's primitive (pointers are primitive types in C).

Comment: I'd say no. A struct is NOT a primitive type, neither is a pointer to a struct.

Comment: @Richard: a struct is not a primitive type, but a pointer is (since you can't get a "part" of a pointer).

Comment: But, if it is primate that means it only carries a hex number of a memory address? But isn't that similar to Object in Java but Object in Java is Object type

Comment: @Owl: unlike Java, ObjC is a wrapper around C, and all its basic types (id, Class, SEL etc) are defined as C pointers. There's no dedicated "Object" type.

Comment: @thg435 NSString *str = @"abc"; str here is a pointer but it is in object type in objective-C. id just hides that pointer.

Comment: After rigours research, finally I found very strong answer from Stanford iOS development lectures :), id is indeed a primitive type. Thanks @thg435

Answer (score 5):

Definitly not a primitive type. From Apple:

In Objective-C, object identifiers are of a distinct data type: id. This type is the general type for any kind of object regardless of class and can be used for instances of a class and for class objects themselves.

Comment: As per the Paul Hegarty Stanford lecturer and former software engineer who was part of the team who build cocoa-touch platform says that id is primitive type :)...Finally the confusion is gone

Comment: @Owl thanks for bringing this and correcting my knowledge. I wish I could found that in Apple's documentation clearly. I will try to find.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that **'id'** from **Objective-C** is a similar type to **void pointer** from plain **'c'**. As pointers are primitives I would guess that 'id' is indeed a primitive type.